# Save photo to camera roll with specific filename

Tags: ios, ipad, camera-roll

What I try to achieve is to take a photo and let the user specify if the photo belongs to category 1 or category 2. I have 2 buttons, one for each category. When the user presses the button, the photo is saved to the camera roll. AFterwards, at home, when I sync my iPad with iPhoto, I want to be able to sort by category, or at least identify to with category it belongs...

I first thought of the following :
1) taking a photo using the iPad camera -- this is already done in my app
2) saving the photo in camera roll under a specific name, such as cat1_pict123.jpg or cat2_pict456.jpg

I would plan to use
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, nil, nil, nil );
but I don't know how / or if it is possible to specify a file name ?

Alternatively, is there a way to "tag" a photo before saving it to camera roll ? A comment or something else, which will be visible in iPhoto ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can't name / rename a file in camera roll.

Comment: You can write your image to the Sandbox of your application though with a name you specify.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use file names for images saved in photolibrary.

Save that to Document directory with specific name.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to kinda do that, by setting the image IPTC metadata:

- Set the field "Object Name" to set the image title in
  iPhoto.
- Set the field "Keywords" to set the keywords in
  iPhoto, then use a smart album to see all the images with these
  keywords.

See details (and code) at http://ootips.org/yonat/how-to-set-the-image-name-when-saving-to-the-camera-roll/ .

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible right now.